# convergence or divergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{k^2-\sin^2(k)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Finding whether the series $$\;\; \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{k^2-\sin^2(k)}$$ is converges or Diverges

What i try

We know that $\sin^2(x)\leq 1$ for all real number.

So $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{k^2-\sin^2(k)}\geq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k}{k^2-1}$$

How do i solve it . Help me please.

Comment: Start at $k=2$ to avoid division by $0$. What is the behavior of $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^2-1}$?

Comment: Thanks Integrand . From $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{k}{k^2-1}\geq\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{k}{k^2}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$ is diverges using $p$ series test. Is i am right

Comment: Note that $\frac{k}{k^2-\sin^2(k)}\ge \frac1{2k}$ for $k\ge 1$.

Comment: The *lower* bound must be $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k^2\color{red}{+}1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

$\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k}{k^2-1}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2(k-1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k+1}$

Can you see where this is going?